# GetFeatures from WMS using angular-openlayers-directive

Tags: openlayers-2, angularjs

How do I get features from a WMS layer using angular-openlayers-directive?
I've been trying to figure that out, but can't find a way to do it.

Comment: WMS is not made for sending features although it is sometimes possible by tweaking with GetFeatureInfo. Study Web Feature Service (WFS) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get features from a WMS layer

**You can't.**

WMS is an interface standard that deals with images. The WMS service converts spatial data (raster or vector source data) into images on request as part of a GetMap request.  There is a corresponding GetFeatureInfo request which returns information on the underlying source data for an image coordinate (from the image returned by the GetMap request).

If you want features (that is vector data) then you need to use a WFS.